# how to add new elements to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I created an array with size (256, 144, 3).

```
empty_windows = np.empty((256, 144, 3))
```

Then I want to append new elements into the array with:

```
for i in range(256):
    for j in range(144):
        empty_windows[i, j] = np.append(empty_windows[i, j], np.asarray(some_new_array)).reshape(3, )
```

But it doesnt work as I get the error msg:
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6 into shape (3,)

Is there a way of doing it? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "append new elements"?  What do you expect the array to look like when you're done?  It looks to me like you don't want append, you just want simple assignment.  If you have an array of 3, just do `empty_windows[i,j] = some_new_array`.

Comment: by i mean "append new elements" is that i want to append a new set of values, which is in the form of array like [x, y, z]. empty_windows[i, j] can receive multiple sets of values

Comment: But you're not "appending new elements".  Your array already contains 256x144x3 values, they just happen to be zeros.  You're just trying to SET the three values at entry [i,j].  That's not appending -- you're not changing the size of the array.  It's just like if you had `xxx = [1,2,3]` and `xxx[1] = 2`.  That's not appending -- it's just setting one entry.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, it will help you understanding concatenate 3dim array

```
import numpy as np
empty_windows = np.empty((256, 144, 3))
random_arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(256, 144, 3)) # it's dimension should be same
np.concatenate([empty_windows, random_arr], axis=2) # it can concatenate into an array axis=2 defines 3rd dimension
```

Comment: The two starts can have different sizes along the axis you are concatenating along. https://tio.run/##VY7BCoMwDIbvfYrADmtBxKnbrU8yhmRasLCmpak49/Ku08O2QxLy8@X/E5Y0emrW1brgYwKaXFgAGSgI40JautnS4GcGnaVyk6Ssz5cCTm1bQKOUiJgJ12GMO7Tv27CUZJXRKje2L6N/Ts9KwQFsOjIM1hli6wl49NNjgLsBRmcE6uzXe@oxGcolr39PFfDNvhWAT8u6VkKE@AnGkkcMRq3rGw

Answer (score 0):

`np.empty` and `np.append` are dangerous functions to use.  They are not clones of the the empty list `[]` and `list.append`.

```
empty_windows = np.empty((256, 144, 3))
```

has made a (256,144,3) shape array with float values - they are unpredictable, but more than likely not what you want.  Look at that array, or a smaller example to see for yourself.  Also read, and if necessary reread, the `np.empty` docs.  `np.zeros` is safer.

With scalar `i,j`,

```
empty_windows[i, j]
```

is a (3,) shape array, or slot.

When you `np.append` it with another (3,) shape, the result is a (6,) shape, with the first 3 value being those "random" values originally in `empty_window`.  The error tells you quite clearly that it can't put a (6,) shape array into a slot that only holds (3,).

Your goal isn't clear, but you can't grow a (n,m,3) shape array to (n,m,6) by doing this kind of "row" by "row" append.

You can set the "row" with new values, as in:

```
    empty_windows[i, j] = np.asarray(some_new_array)).reshape(3, )
```